# Is there an open source project available to display web page response time on Google maps?

Tags: html, google-maps, responsive-design, single-page-application

Given a webpage available worldwide and a datastore with response times of the webpage request from various locations worldwide ( Example: Datastore having json data such as {HKG :1, LON : 0.7, Chicago :0.2}.
 I want to display this data with a live refresh every 5 seconds on a webpage using HTML5 Maps.

Is there an opensource solution available with responsive web to display worldmap? 
I am planning to explore [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation). However not sure about the responsive web part of the display. Webpage needs to be responsive on Tablet, TV and Desktop. 
Is there any open source solution available to display worldmap with custom markers options and responsive in nature?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick demo of one approach you could use:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/pupkvkkc/

This fiddle is a hack of a [Highchart Highmap](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo), my demo used http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon as a starting point.

Of course you would need to modify the map as required. Then pull in the dynamic data, perhaps by importing it from an associated json file which includes the name, latitude and longitude, and the response time for each of the locations you are monitoring.

Finally you would setup your HTML page to automatically refresh every 5sec.   One way to do this would be to include a refresh meta tag the head of your page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/page.htm">
```

If you need help with how to import your dynamic data, check out some of the other Highchart demos, e.g. [this fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-bubble/) imports [this json file](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population.json) at line 3 of the javascript

Highchart isn't open source, though you can download it for free.

Good luck!

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/gb/gb-all.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height: 680px;
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {

    // Initiate the chart
    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

        title: {
            text: 'Hover over location to see datastore response times'
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '',
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b><br> {point.response_time} sec'
        },

        series: [{
            // Use the gb-all map with no data as a basemap
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/gb/gb-all'],
            name: 'Basemap',
            borderColor: '#A0A0A0',
            nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3)',
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            name: 'Separators',
            type: 'mapline',
            data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/gb/gb-all'], 'mapline'),
            color: '#707070',
            showInLegend: false,
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }, {
            // Specify points using lat/lon
            type: 'mappoint',
            name: 'Datastore locations',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            data: [{
                name: 'London',
                lat: 51.507222,
                lon: -0.1275,
                response_time:1.0
            },{
                name: 'Glasgow',
                lat: 55.858,
                lon: -4.259,
                response_time:0.9
            }, {
                name: 'Belfast',
                lat: 54.597,
                lon: -5.93,
                response_time:1.2
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```